# Issues redirecting only top-level domain to https via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

i am trying to redirect my top level domain to https, but not any subdomains.

Here is what i have.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site.eu$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.eu/$1 [R,L]
```

How do i make it ignore subdomains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?site\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

`^(?:www\.)?site\.eu$` will only match top level doain.